# How can i print tqdm progress bar on sameline?

Tags: python, eclipse, tqdm

I am trying to put a progress bar in my for loop but the progress bar is shifted to next line after each iteration.
How can i put it in a single line?
I am using eclipse and the code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
import datetime
from tqdm import trange


i=0
for i in trange(b):
    day = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="aaaaa"]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[@style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 0); color: rgb(128, 0, 0);"]')
    day[i].click()

    time.sleep(2)

    download = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content1"]/div/div[4]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a[2]')
    download.click()

    driver.get('https://npp.gov.in/dgrReports') 

    pre_month = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="aaaaa"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]')
    pre_month.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with Eclipse console. These steps worked for me:

In Eclipse,

- Go to `Window` -> `Preferences`.
- Expand `Run/Debug`, and select `Console`.
- On the right, enable `Interpret ASCII control characters`.

[image: Eclipse Console Preferences with Interpret ASCII control characters option enabled]